# Filtering a django news post

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I have a news post and on that same template I have a section on the right hand side displaying all of the latest posts. However when you are on one of the main news posts it also shows up in the 'latest news' tab on the right.

I'm pretty sure i need to use .exclude to filter out the one that is being displayed. However i don't know how django know which post is being displayed.

If you need to look at my code please ask. I'm only using basic models / views to output the data.

The line that shows the latest 3 posts:

```
other_news = NewsPost.objects.filter(live=True, categories__in=post.categories.all).distinct().order_by("-posted")[:3]
```

Code for the template:

```
<div class='related_article_wrapper'>
            {% if other_news %}
                {% for news in other_news %}

                <div class="article_snipppet_wrap">

                    <img class="article_icon" src="/media/images/article_icon.png"  alt="" />
                        <p>{{news.title}}</p>
                        <span><a href="{{news.get_absolute_url}}">{{news.posted|date:"d/m/y"}} &#187;</a></span>

                </div>


            {% endfor %}
            <span><a style="text-decoration: none; href="/news-hub/news/">View all news &#187;</a></span>
            {% endif %}

            </div>
```

Thanks,

Josh

Comment: Please show us some of your relevant code!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `.exclude(id=post.id)` to your filter chain:

```
other_news = NewsPost.objects.exclude(id=post.id).filter(live=True,    
    categories__in=post.categories.all).distinct().order_by("-posted")[:3]
```

[`exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) takes arguments in the same format as `filter()`, it just does the opposite!

Comment: YES! Thanks so much! Really appreciate it! Massive help! :)